# Optimizing pure magus for single turn damage

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, magus

As per title I'm looking for ways to optimize a magus meant mainly for assassination and boss-dispatching. I know about the shocking grasp "trick", but I feel that's not enough for higher-level characters.

Specifics:

- Prestige classes and archetypes are allowed
- No multi-classing otherwise
- Only official Paizo material available
- Character level 10+
- Character has "decent" to-hit bonuses, through either feats or arcana.

Preferred:

- Not having only 1 type of elemental damage
- No traits

Answer (score 2):

For combating single opponents, one of the more potentially lethal archetypes for a magus is the Hexcrafter. 
Hexcrafter to gain the slumber hex, and possibly the evil eye/misfortune hexes.
Take the Elemental Spell metamagic and the Maximized/Empowered magus arcana.

It would allow for a coup-de-grace requiring a pair of natural 20s to survive while still inflicting a great deal of damage.

The damage(done with a basic scimitar/rapier) with a strength score of 14, will be 2D6+4(weapon) + 15d6(spell). This will result in 11(average weapon damage) + 90(Maximized spell damage), for a total of 101. The DC of a Fort save vs Coup-de-grace is equal to the damage dealt(101) + 10, for an average DC of 111.

Comment: What part of a coup-de-grace forces you to make a pair of natural 20's? Even with the misfortune hex, the DC isn't that high.

Comment: The part where the coup-de-grace is from a maximized, empowered, and possibly Elemental shocking grasp critical hit for 15d6(or 90 + base weapon critical damage) or around 100 points of damage minimum. Coup-de-grace Fort DC is 10 + damage dealt. If you know of anything that can make that save without a natural 20, please let me know.

Comment: While Coup de Grace is powerful, this method relies on getting Slumber to stick first, which can be difficult, considering it is will negates and mind-affecting.

Comment: Except Shocking Grasp caps out at 5d6, or 30 damage (45 with empowered). Normally that would be doubled on a crit, but I don't think that happens with the magus spell delivery system.

Comment: It follows all the normal rules for critical hits when delivered as a Spellstrike, or 10d6, then Empowered to 15d6.   As to the Slumber DC, invisibility, evil eye, Hexing runes and an very high intelligence are the solution.

Comment: @Guest It's probably clear from outside knowledge to the OP what's delivering the crit, but I would recommend editing your answer to make that explicitly clear, as well as what the actual expected Fort DC is (~110).

Comment: ["An empowered, maximized spell gains the separate benefits of each feat: the maximum result plus half the normally rolled result."](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/maximize-spell-metamagic---final) Maximize does not maximize the empowered part, bringing the damage down to 60+5d6, averaging 77,5 instead of 90.

Comment: Also, [Intensified Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/intensified-spell-metamagic) is definitely noteworthy (and no Magus should ever not have it, at least in Rod form), bringing the base damage up to 10d6, for a total of 20*6+10d6, averaging 155 points of damage.